# Select WHERE Almacen='.$filtros'

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

```
$filtros= '**HOME**';
echo $filtros;

$offset = 20;

$from = 0; 

$sql_statement = 'SELECT * FROM remitos WHERE Almacen='.$filtros' ORDER BY fecha ASC LIMIT ' . $from . ',' . $offset;
$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);
```

I need help with this code, the WHERE statement is not working

Comment: When downvoting, please leave a comment so the question can be improved.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Try turning on some of the php error/warning reporting facilities so that your code will generate a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a concatenator (dot) after `$filtros`.

Also, I suggest quoting your fields and input values.

You can include a `die()` statement to output any errors.

```
$sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM `remitos`
  WHERE `Almacen`='".$filtros."'
  ORDER BY `fecha` ASC LIMIT ".$from.",".$offset;

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement) or die(mysql_error());
```

Consider using PDO instead, as `mysql_*` statements are [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and you could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

One point is missing after your var :

```
'.$filtros.'
```

to concatenate strings correctly